# How to find if there's a path between every pair of vertices of a given graph?

Tags: c++, graph, graph-theory, depth-first-search

To find if there's a path between every pair of vertices in a directed graph I'm checking if all vertices can be visited from a specific vertex using DFS. The problem is that I have to do V DFS's where V is the number of vertices. (V can be up to 10^5). Is there a more efficient way to do this? Some pseudo-code or implementations would be appreciated.

Consider this graph: (1 -> 3), (2 -> 3), (3 -> 1)

There' no path from 1 to 2, but there's a path from 2 to 1 (2 -> 3 -> 1). So this means that there's a path for every pair of vertices (u -> v) even if there's no path (v -> u).

Comment: Is this a directed or undirected graph? You could check if the graph includes more than one strongly connected component

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to mention that but it's a directed graph. I'll edit it.

Comment: Then you are looking for [Strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component)

Comment: "A graph is said to be strongly connected if every vertex is reachable from every other vertex" - I don't actually need every vertex to be reachable from every other vertex. I just need to know if there's a path from u to v or v to u for every pair.

Comment: What's the difference between "a path must exist between every pair of vertices" and "a path must exist from each vertex to all others" ?

Comment: I've just edited my question, maybe you will get more into what I asking.

Comment: I think you can solve this by running your DFS logic on a graph of strongly connected components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find if there is a single path that visits all vertices of a directed graph (which can visit vertices and edges multiple times) then:

1. Find the [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Algorithms) [SCC] of the graph.
2. Reduce the graph replacing each SCC with a single "pseudo-vertex" and include the edges connecting the SCCs.
3. The graph will now contain no cycles (since every cycle would have been part of an SCC) so will be a rooted graph/tree and there must be:

   - One-or-more root pseudo-vertices (with no inbound edges);
   - One-or-more leaf pseudo-vertices (with no outbound edges; which can be a leaf and a root vertex at the same time); and
   - Zero-or-more pseudo-vertices which are part of a branch (with both inbound and outbound edges).
4. Trivially, each leaf and part of a branch will be reachable from an ancestor pseudo-vertex (since they have inbound edges) but it is not possible to reach one branch from another parallel branch so we only need to consider whether the resulting graph is a simple path with no branches.
5. Count the number of root vertices:

   - If there is a single root pseudo-vertex (SCC) then any vertex contained in that SCC can reach all other vertices in the graph;
   - If there is more than 1 root pseudo-vertex then there is no vertex that has a path to all other vertices (since you cannot reach one root from a different root).
6. If the singular root pseudo-vertex and each subsequent descendant pseudo-vertex only has a single outbound edge (i.e. there are no branches) until the leaf is reached then the resulting graph has contains a path that can reach all vertices.

**Examples**:

After reducing the SCCs to pseudo-vertices if the graph is of the form:

```
(1) -> (2) -> ... (n-1) -> (n)
```

Then there is a path that can visit all vertices.

If it is of the form:

```
(1_a) --\
         +--> (2) -> ... (n-1) -> (n)
(1_b) --/
```

Then the vertex `(1_a)` is not reachable from `(1_b)` and vice-versa so there is no path that can reach all vertices.

Similarly:

```
                    /-> (n_a)
(1) -> (2) -> ... -+
                    \-> n_b
```

Then the vertex `(n_a)` is not reachable from `(n_b)` and vice-versa so there is no path that can reach all vertices.

And finally, if it is the form:

```
                    /-> (x_a) -\
(1) -> (2) -> ... -+            +-> ... (n-1) -> (n)
                    \-> (x_b) -/
```

Then there no path that can reach both `(x_a)` and `(x_b)`.

Comment: That actually works now I've to spend some good time trying implementing this... Thanks!

Comment: @FernandoMussel Thanks for the edit suggestion - I considered one additional case over your suggestion and re-edited the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Tarjan's algorithm for strongly connected components. If only one strongly connected component exists, this means there exists a path between every pair of vertices.

To figure this out, do a topological sort of the graph, and then traverse it in reverse pseudo-topological order. If you don't need to 'restart' a traversal this means, this means there exists a path between every possible vertex.

Comment: I've edited my question. I think that in the graph I gave as example there's two SCC's, right? But anyway, there's at least one path between all vertices.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why some answer seems so unnecessarily complicated. In fact, you can just use the topological sort of the graph, and check whether there is an edge connecting each node and its subsequent node.